# proving a median in a triangle base on center of mass

Tags: geometry, triangles

I was wondering: I know that the center of mass in a triangle is divided the medians in the ratio of $2:1$.

Is the opposite is true?

I mean, if i have triangle $ABC$ and point $D$ is on $BC$, point $E$ is on $AB$ such that the point of intersection, divided $AD,CE$ in the ratio of $2:1$.

Can i say that $AD,CE$ are medians?

**In Addition**: what about if i have one median and a point on that median that dividing it by the ration of $2:1$, is it true to say that this point will definitely be the center of mass?

Thanks.

Comment: The assumption is right, but I don't know the proof for it.

Comment: Yes, that much is also enough to determine the triangle and its medians. (You must mark the point 2/3rds away from the vertex of the to-be triangle.)

Comment: Yes, the converse is true by Ceva's and Van Obel's theorems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest proof I know is using analytic (coordinate) geometry.

[image]

Given that CE and AD are divided as given, then
$$
\frac23E+\frac13C=F=\frac23D+\frac13A\tag{1}
$$
Add $\frac13B$ to both sides and multiply by $\frac32$ and subtract $D+E$:
$$
\underbrace{\frac12(C+B)-D}_{\text{parallel to $CB$}}=\underbrace{\frac12(A+B)-E}_{\text{parallel to $AB$}}\tag{2}
$$
Since $CB\not\parallel AB$, both sides of $(2)$ must be $0$. That is
$$
D=\frac{C+B}2\quad\text{and}\quad E=\frac{A+B}2\tag{3}
$$

---

**Additional Problem**

At the beginning of your question, it is given that the center of mass divides each median into two segments whose lengths have a ratio of $2:1$. There are only two points that divide a given line segment into lengths with a ratio of $2:1$. By what was given at the beginning of the question, one of those points must be the center of mass, and the other must be halfway between the center of mass and one of the vertices.

[image]

Comment: coordinate geometry ought to be the last resort for these kind of problems.

Comment: thanks but i asked about the opposite.

Comment: @yashg: I would consider using Ceva to require more background, partly because we first need to prove that the three medians are coincident, but as you say, these are opinions.

Comment: @ruth: that direction is easier. I have adjusted my answer.

Comment: @robjohn - can you add also about my ADDITION question?, because your proof is in my tools of knowledge. the others are very nice but i didn't learn  Menelaus' theorem nor ceva's theorem.

Comment: do i need to prove that There are only two points that divide a given line segment into lengths with a ratio of 2:1? or it's trivial?

Comment: @ruth: If one piece is twice the length of the other, then because $x+2x=1$, we have that $x=\frac13$. That is, one piece must be $\frac13$ and the other $\frac23$. Which one contains the vertex is arbitrary, so there are $2$ ways to divide the segment into a ratio of $2:1$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the triangle ABC as shown with $AG:GD=2$ and $BG:GE=2$.
[image]

Now applying [Menelaus' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus%27_theorem) in triangles $\Delta ADC$ and $\Delta BEC$ you will obtain the following relations:

$$\frac{BD\cdot EC}{BC\cdot AE}=\frac{1}{2}$$

$$\frac{AE\cdot DC}{AC\cdot DB}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Now take $\frac{EC}{EA}=p$ and $\frac{DC}{DB}=q$ and rewrie above relations as :

$$\frac{p}{1+q}=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\frac{q}{1+p}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Solving for $p$ and $q$ will yield the required result.

**ADDITION** Draw $\Delta ABC$ and medians $AD$ and $BE$. Let $G$ be the point that divides $AD$ in the ratio $2:1$ and try proving that $BG$ and $BF$ are part of the same line. Doing so we can conclude that $G$ is the point of concurrency of the medians.

Hint: This can be done with many tools, including similarity, ceva's and menelaus' theorem.

Comment: nice. i went the longer way.

Comment: can you explain about my ADDITION question? and thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

this is true.

let $AD$ and $BE$ cut at $G.$  let $GA = 2x, GD = x, GC= 2z, GE = z, GB = w, GF = y$ where extended $BG$ meets the side $AC$ at $F.$  we want to show that $w = 2y.$

we will use ceva's theorem that tells you $\frac{BD}{DC} \frac{CF}{FA} \frac{AE}{EB} = 1$  we will get the relations among the areas of six triangles:

$$\frac{AGE}{CGD} = 1, \frac{EGB}{CFG} = \frac{w}{2y}, \frac{BGD}{AFG} = \frac{w}{2y} = \frac{1}{\alpha} $$

$\begin{align}
1 &=\frac{BD}{DC} \frac{CF}{FA} \frac{AE}{EB} \\
&= \frac{BGD+BGE+AEG}{CDG+CGF+AGF}
\frac{CGF+CGD+BGD}{AGF+AGE+BGE} \frac{AGE+AGF+CGF}{BGE+BGD+CGD} \\
&=\frac{BGD+BGE+AEG}{AGE+\alpha EGB+\alpha BGD}
\frac{\alpha EGB+AGE+BGD}{\alpha BGD+AGE+BGE} \frac{AGE+\alpha BGD+\alpha EGB}{BGE+BGD+AGE} \\
&=\frac{\alpha EGB+AGE+BGD}{\alpha BGD+AGE+BGE} \\
\end{align}$

the last equality gives you $\alpha = 1$ and $w = 2y.$